# Can't get response from jQuery AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, google-chrome

When I want clients to stop long-polling, I send back an AJAX response of

```
"HUPWAIT"
```

And this is what the response looks like in firebug.

[image: The response in FF.]

But when I try to grab the AJAX response in my js, both of the following return false in Firefox and IE9:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/wait",
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data == "\"HUPWAIT\""); //returns false
      console.log(data == "HUPWAIT"); //also returns false
});
```

Interestingly, the same code returns true in Chrome:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/wait",
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data == "\"HUPWAIT\""); //returns true in Chrome
});
```

And when I try to debug in Firefox (with firebug) using the following code, I get a weird response:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/wait",
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); //returns Document
      console.log(''+data); //returns [object XMLDocument]
});
```

The headers look normal:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: XXXXXXXXXX
Date: Mon, 10 Sep 2012 23:40:34 GMT
Server: nginx/1.2.3
```

But there is something weird in the XML tab of firebug:

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: moz-nullprincipal:{16915058-4ead-41ef-a63e-1265ee278d74} Line Number 1, Column 1:
"HUPWAIT"
 ^
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox/IE will attempt to parse the AJAX (X=XML) response as an XML document, producing the error you see in the debugger.  Adding a "Content-Type" header to the response (`text/plain`) will force the browser to process the text correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried specifying `dataType` in the AJAX call?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/wait",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data == "\"HUPWAIT\""); //returns false
        console.log(data == "HUPWAIT"); //also returns false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also check the raw responseText:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/wait",
    success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText == "\"HUPWAIT\"");
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText == "HUPWAIT");
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```